# TDUnitX output doesn't show the number of asserts

Tags: delphi, dunitx

I am using Delphi 12.1 (trail) and have the following configuration:

```
program WalterNativeTests;

{$IFNDEF TESTINSIGHT}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}
{$STRONGLINKTYPES ON}
uses
  FastMM4,
  DUnitX.MemoryLeakMonitor.FastMM4,
  System.SysUtils,
  {$IFDEF TESTINSIGHT}
  TestInsight.DUnitX,
  {$ELSE}
  DUnitX.Loggers.Console,
  DUnitX.Loggers.Xml.NUnit,
  {$ENDIF }
  DUnitX.TestFramework,
  StringUtilsTest in 'StringUtilsTest.pas',
  EncryptionTests in 'EncryptionTests.pas';

{ keep comment here to protect the following conditional from being removed by the IDE when adding a unit }
{$IFNDEF TESTINSIGHT}
var
  runner: ITestRunner;
  results: IRunResults;
  logger: ITestLogger;
  nunitLogger : ITestLogger;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IFDEF TESTINSIGHT}
  TestInsight.DUnitX.RunRegisteredTests;
{$ELSE}
  try
    //Check command line options, will exit if invalid
    TDUnitX.CheckCommandLine;
    //Create the test runner
    runner := TDUnitX.CreateRunner;

    //Tell the runner to use RTTI to find Fixtures
    runner.UseRTTI := True;

    //When true, Assertions must be made during tests;
    runner.FailsOnNoAsserts := True;

    //tell the runner how we will log things
    //Log to the console window if desired
    if TDUnitX.Options.ConsoleMode <> TDunitXConsoleMode.Off then
    begin
      logger := TDUnitXConsoleLogger.Create(TDUnitX.Options.ConsoleMode = TDunitXConsoleMode.Quiet);
      runner.AddLogger(logger);
    end;
    //Generate an NUnit compatible XML File
    nunitLogger := TDUnitXXMLNUnitFileLogger.Create(TDUnitX.Options.XMLOutputFile);
    runner.AddLogger(nunitLogger);

    TDUnitX.Options.ExitBehavior := TDUnitXExitBehavior.Pause;


    TDUnitX.Options.ShowUsage := True;


    //Run tests
    results := runner.Execute;
    if not results.AllPassed then
      System.ExitCode := EXIT_ERRORS;

    {$IFNDEF CI}
    //We don't want this happening when running under CI.
    if TDUnitX.Options.ExitBehavior = TDUnitXExitBehavior.Pause then
    begin
      System.Write('Done.. press <Enter> key to quit.');
      System.Readln;
    end;
    {$ENDIF}
  except
    on E: Exception do
      System.Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

Al my tests have **asserts="0"**

```
<test-case name="RoundTripTest" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.009" asserts="0"/>
```

what am I missing, I am sure I have more han zero asserts in the tests...

```
procedure EncyptionTest.RoundTripTest;
const password:string ='pa$$w0rd123';
const secret: string = 'This is a secret string that no one is allowed to be able to read';
var encrypted,decrypted:string;

begin
  encrypted:= SymmetricEncrypt(password,11000,secret);
  decrypted:= SymmetricDecrypt(password,11000,encrypted);
  Assert.AreEqual(secret,decrypted);
  Assert.AreNotEqual(encrypted,decrypted);
end;
```